# Disable or lock parent pages from being edited in wordpress admin

Tags: wp-admin, pages

Is there a way to disable or lock parent pages from being edited in wordpress admin?
I only want the children pages to be editable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Save this code as plugin and activate one. Plugin will lock all pages that has children from edit.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Lock parent pages form edit
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1
Author: Alexey Selin <alexey.a.selin@gmail.com>
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/7314/alexey
*/

function lock_parent_pages_from_edit( $capauser, $capask, $param){
    global $wpdb;
    $post = get_post( $param[2] );
    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
    if( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
        if( $param[0] == "edit_page" ) {
              foreach( (array) $capask as $capasuppr) {
                 if ( array_key_exists($capasuppr, $capauser) ) {
                    $capauser[$capasuppr] = 0;
                 }
              }
        }
    }
    return $capauser;
}
add_filter('user_has_cap', 'lock_parent_pages_from_edit', 100, 3 );
?>
```

Comment: This works, however not quite what I was after. I am sorry I worded this wrong. I want to lock all pages at the top level. not just ones with children.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. This is what I did: ' function lock_parent_pages_from_edit( $capauser, $capask, $param){
    global $wpdb;
    $post = get_post( $param[2] );
    if($post->post_parent == 0) {
        if( $param[0] == "edit_page" ) {
              foreach( (array) $capask as $capasuppr) {
                 if ( array_key_exists($capasuppr, $capauser) ) {
                    $capauser[$capasuppr] = 0;
                 }
              }
        }
    }
    return $capauser;
}
add_filter('user_has_cap', 'lock_parent_pages_from_edit', 100, 3 );'

Comment: Correction. I still want to be able to add child pages to the top level page. I just want the top level page to not be editable. Make sense?

Comment: What is stopping you from add child pages to the top level pages? I tested your updated code on my machine, it works, and i can add child pages.